# Time condition loop in shell

Tags: shell

I have just started learning shell script recently, so I don't know much about it.

I am trying to find example of time based while loop but not having any luck.

I want to run a loop for specific amount of time, let's say 1 hour. So loop runs for an hour and then ends automatically.

Edit: This loop will run continiously without any sleep, so the loop condition should be based on loop's start time and current time, not on sleep.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the $SECONDS variable, which has a count of the time that the script (or shell) has been running for. The below sample shows how to run a while loop for 3 seconds.

```
#! /bin/bash
end=$((SECONDS+3))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
    # Do what you want.
    :
done
```

Comment: this is supported by bash and probably other bourne shell variants, but i'm not sure it's in the POSIX spec, so you should be clear to specify a hash-bang shell more specific than `#!/bin/sh` (which this answer did, but i'm just pointing it out).

Comment: +1 for use of `$SECONDS`; @RobStarling: it is indeed NOT part of POSIX (see my answer for a POSIX-only solution); non-exhaustive survey: `$SECONDS` works in `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`. In `ksh` it even reports fractional seconds.

Answer (score 36):

**Caveat**: All solutions in this answer - except the `ksh` one - can return *up to (but not including) 1 second early*, since they're based on an integral-seconds counter that advances based on the *real-time (system) clock* rather than based on *when code execution started*.

---

#### `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` solution, using special shell variable `$SECONDS`:

Slightly simplified version of @bsravanin's answer.

Loosely speaking, `$SECONDS` contains the number of seconds elapsed so far in a script.

In `bash` and `zsh` you get *integral* seconds advancing by the pulse of the *system (real-time) clock* - i.e., *counting behind the scenes does not truly start at `0`(!), but at whatever fraction since the last full time-of-day second the script happened to be started at or the `SECONDS` variable was reset.*

By contrast, `ksh` operates as one would expect: counting truly starts at `0` when you reset `$SECONDS`; furthermore, `$SECONDS` reports *fractional* seconds in `ksh`.

**Therefore, the only shell in which this solution works *reasonably predictably and precisely* is `ksh`**. That said, **for *rough* measurements and timeouts it may still be usable in `bash` and `zsh`**.

Note: The following uses a `bash` shebang line; simply substituting `ksh` or `zsh` for `bash` will make the script run with these shells, too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

secs=3600   # Set interval (duration) in seconds.

SECONDS=0   # Reset $SECONDS; counting of seconds will (re)start from 0(-ish).
while (( SECONDS < secs )); do    # Loop until interval has elapsed.
  # ...
done
```

---

#### Solution for POSIX-features-only shells, such as `sh` (`dash`) on Ubuntu (`$SECONDS` is not POSIX-compliant)

Cleaned-up version of @dcpomero's answer.

Uses epoch time returned by `date +%s` (seconds elapsed since 1 January 1970) and POSIX syntax for the conditional.

*Caveat*: `date +%s` itself (specifically, the `%s` format) is *not* POSIX-compliant, but it'll work on (at least) Linux, FreeBSD, and OSX.

```
#!/bin/sh

secs=3600                         # Set interval (duration) in seconds.
endTime=$(( $(date +%s) + secs )) # Calculate end time.

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do  # Loop until interval has elapsed.
    # ...
done
```

Comment: It seems as if SECONDS=0 resets the variables to again represent the elapsed time since the script was started.  SECONDS=1 will set the timer starting from 1 instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `loop` command, available [here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Loop), like so:

```
$ loop './do_thing.sh' --for-duration 1h --every 5s
```

Which will do the your thing every five seconds for one hour.

Comment: really nice, but it is not a standard :/

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
starttime = `date +%s`
while [ $(( $(date +%s) - 3600 )) -lt $starttime ]; do
done
```

where `'date +%s'` gives the current time in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

`date +%s` will give you the seconds since the epoch, so something like

```
startTime = `date +%s`
timeSpan = #some number of seconds
endTime = timeSpan + startTime

while (( `date +%s` < endTime )) ; do
    #code
done
```

You might need some edits, since my bash is rusty

Comment: Promising, but your code breaks for a number of reasons; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the `-d` option of `date`.

Below is a shell script snippet to exemplify.  It is similar to other answers, but may be more useful in different scenarios.

```
# set -e to exit if the time provided by argument 1 is not valid for date.
# The variable stop_date will store the seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
# UTC, according to the date specified by -d "$1".
set -e
stop_date=$(date -d "$1" "+%s")
set +e

echo -e "Starting at $(date)"
echo -e "Finishing at $(date -d "$1")"

# Repeat the loop while the current date is less than stop_date
while [ $(date "+%s") -lt ${stop_date} ]; do

    # your commands that will run until stop_date

done
```

You can then call the script in the many different ways date understands:

```
$ ./the_script.sh "1 hour 4 minutes 3 seconds"
Starting at Fri Jun  2 10:50:28 BRT 2017
Finishing at Fri Jun  2 11:54:31 BRT 2017

$ ./the_script.sh "tomorrow 8:00am"
Starting at Fri Jun  2 10:50:39 BRT 2017
Finishing at Sat Jun  3 08:00:00 BRT 2017

$ ./the_script.sh "monday 8:00am"
Starting at Fri Jun  2 10:51:25 BRT 2017
Finishing at Mon Jun  5 08:00:00 BRT 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what I was looking for, 
here is a one line solution based on bsravanin's answer:

end=$((SECONDS+30)); of=$((end-SECONDS)) ; while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do echo $((end-SECONDS)) seconds left of $of ; sleep 1 ; done;

Answer (score 0):

For a more modern approach...

### Bash

```
declare -ir MAX_SECONDS=5
declare -ir TIMEOUT=$SECONDS+$MAX_SECONDS

while (( $SECONDS < $TIMEOUT )); do
    # foo
done
```

### Korn

```
typeset -ir MAX_SECONDS=5
typeset -ir TIMEOUT=$SECONDS+$MAX_SECONDS

while (( $SECONDS < $TIMEOUT )); do
    # bar
done
```