# Executing bash script via java in background after ssh connection is closed

Tags: java, linux, bash, ssh, parallel-processing

I am using java to execute a simple bash script on a remote linux machine.

The bash script named "shortoracle.bash" have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
runsql() {
   i="$1"
   end=$((SECONDS+360))
   SECONDS=0
   while (( SECONDS < end )); do
   echo "INSERT into table_$i (col1) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);" | sqlplus username/password
   sleep 1
   done
}


for i in $(seq 1 10); do
 echo "DROP TABLE table_$i;" | sqlplus username/password
 echo "CREATE TABLE table_$i (col1 TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);" | sqlplus username/password
 runsql $i &
done
wait
```

Simply speaking: create 10 parallel connection that execute queries for 360 seconds.

From my java program i execute the following command:

```
sshconnection.execute("nohup su - oracle -c './shortoracle.bash'",2000);
```

The ssh executes the script successfully.

I want,after a timeout of 2 seconds (the second param) to terminate the ssh connection, but for the script to continue to run properly in the background (therefore the nohup, or so i thought), it's not happening:

After 2 seconds when i terminate the sshconnection, the bash program just stops working:

- Only 3 of the 10 connections are open.
- No more inserts happening.

If i give the connection a longer timeout, all is going well, but i don't want to hangup on this specific connection, i need to move on with the program.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It's my java program way to establish ssh connection to the remote server, sshcontext if it means anything to you.

Comment: Yes, but i don't think it's the issue, is it?

Comment: The issue is not the ssh executor, it works well, think of it as an abstract method for connecting and executing scripts on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `&` after your command, i.e.

`sshconnection.execute("nohup su - oracle -c './shortoracle.bash' &",2000);`

Since nohup itself will otherwise get disconnected when you close the SSH 
connection. With `&` you run 'nohup' itself in the background and therefore allow it to continue running after you close the SSH connection.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Is the order of the & is right?, i should do su - oracle before

Comment: Ideally I would do it like this: `su - oracle -c 'nohup  ./shortoracle.bash &'` to make sure it only runs in the background for the user `oracle`. Let me know if that works for you than I will update the answer accordingly :) ( I cant test it locally atm)

Comment: It must be with the nohup in the start of the script, it went crazy just now

Comment: Then I would write it like this: `nohup su - oracle -c './shortoracle.bash' &`

Comment: Still not working, when 2000 elapsed, it just stops with the inserts...

Comment: Should this provide any leads? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine?rq=1

Comment: And: `nohup su - oracle -c 'nohup ./shortoracle.bash &' &` to ensure both process are detached?

Comment: Did that also...still no inserts happening.